# Why i Get Access Violation When i tried to access Lambda Local Variable Via Address

Tags: c++

hello guys I have a problem with an Event Manager

first I have A Lambda that responsible for sending the event to my event Manager

```
glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(m_Window, [](GLFWwindow* window , int Width , int Height) {

WindowData Data = *(WindowData*)glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);

WindowResize ReSize(Data.ID, Width, Height);

EventsManager::Get().PushEvent(&ReSize);

});
```

PushEvent Function should push back the pointer to the event queue which is on std:: vector<IEvent*>

```
void EventsManager::PushEvent(IEvent* e)
{
    m_EventsQueue.push_back(e);
}
```

actually this method is working fine when I have a single event but when I have multiple events in a row I got an access violation.

I just want to understand why this is happening and how I can work around this?

Comment: `EventsManager::Get().PushEvent(&ReSize);` -- You are storing the address of a local variable.  What happens when that function block exits?  That local variable is no longer valid, thus you now have stored the address of an invalid `Resize`.

Comment: *actually this method is working fine when I have a single event* -- It really wasn't working fine.  The behavior was undefined all along.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  thanks, you are right But what should do in this case, I can't pass a complete copy and store it on Vector because IEvent is a Pure abstract Class? what do you think the best option here without dynamic allocation, dose stack memory allocator would be overkill?